# phpMyAdmin set with blank user and pass, but 'allownopassword' is set to false, possible to log in?

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin

Trying to log into a customer's phpMyAdmin, I can see the phpMyAdmin config file on the server, but I don't have permissions to update it.

As title says, phpMyAdmin is set with blank user and pass, but 'allownopassword' is set to FALSE.

My best guess is that these settings are conflicting.

I've tried to log in with blank user and pass, but it kicks me out. Is there any way to log in?

Comment: 'allownopassword'=true allows to login with a blank password, but not with a blank username. In your case it's false, so you need to specify both username and password.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin prompts you for a username and a password. Yes, it will reject any connection attempt with no password. But even if it was allowed by PMA, does such a user exist on the MySQL database? I hope not. Then you need to provide a valid username and password.

Comment: So it will accept the user/pass that is set in the config file, as well as any valid MySQL user/pass?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
User as `root` with no password ?

Go to your xampp or lampp directory and there is a file called "passwords.txt" Open and see the loin deatails

Comment: Yes, I have tried a variety of usernames and passwords, including root with blank password. It is a linux server, what path would passwords.txt typically be in?

Comment: I'm having a windows machine. Can you please give a search it with in your lampp or xampp directory ? It shows only default user names and passwords. There was a file which contain the exact username and password. I'll feather search and let you now.

Comment: I found a way to rest the password in Linux systems in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).Just give a try to reset your password as in the "C.5.4.1.2. Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems" section.